# Is it bad practice to use Object instead of declaring a type when using Flow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I have a function with the following declaration:

```
export default (path: string, rules: Object): Promise<Object> =>
  ...
```

I know how the rules should look, should I create a type Rules?

```
type Rules = {
  ...
}
```

And is it possible to configure Flow and Babel in a way that is going to check the type after transpiling the code?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by “Is it possible to configure Flow and Babel in a way that is going to check the type after transpiling the code?”?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to opt-out of using Flow’s type checker, [the way to do it is](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/any/) by using `any`, not `Object`.

Flow’s documentation make it quite clear that is is something that should be avoided, given that it defeats the purpose of using Flow as a type checker in the first place.

Given you say that you already know what the `Rules` type is, I would strongly recommend that you create the `Rules` type and use it instead of `Object`. It looks as though you `Rules` type is going to be an Object Type, so have a look at [Flow’s documentation about Object Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/).

As for your follow up question, it doesn’t really make sense for Flow to type check Babel’s transpiled code. [You should be running `flow status` to type check your code.](https://flow.org/en/docs/usage/) Babel removes Flow’s type annotations because they are syntax errors in normal JavaScript. Type checking and transpiling are different things.